# Trouble with ffmpeg_movie_from_frames in MoviePy - TypeError

Tags: python, ffmpeg, video-processing, moviepy

I'm encountering an issue when using the `ffmpeg_movie_from_frames` function in MoviePy. Here's my code:

```
from moviepy.video.io.ffmpeg_tools import ffmpeg_movie_from_frames

input_folder = r"C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\dist\images"
output_file = r"C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\dist\v.mp4"
fps = 60.0

ffmpeg_movie_from_frames(output_file, input_folder, fps)
```

I'm getting a "TypeError: %d format: a real number is required, not str" error. How can I resolve this and successfully create a video from a series of images with the correct frame rate?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!